# Why doesn't df$"columnname" work in a function?

Tags: r

Why can't I retrieve a column using `df$"columnname"` from within a function, when it works perfectly fine outside of one?

With a dataframe:

```
> df <- as.data.frame(cbind(col1=c(0,1), col2=c(2,3)))
> df
     col1 col2
[1,]    0    2
[2,]    1    3
```

`df$"col1"` works fine normally. However, this returns NULL when I put it in a function.

```
> df_fn <- function(name) { df$name }
> df_fn("col1")
NULL
```

However, it works perfectly fine when I use the `[[]]` form:

```
> df_fn2 <- function(name) { df[[name]] }
> df_fn2("col1")
[1] 0 1
```

---

Looked around and didn't see any answers to this (though it was hard trying to search a symbol like $). Practically speaking, I can use the `[[]]` form just fine, but I'm curious as to what in R's internals causes this.

Comment: if you want help from a symbol, just use quotes = `?"$"`

Comment: Thanks. I might have missed it, but I don't see anything in the docs that address this point? The docs mention `x$name is equivalent to x[["name", exact = FALSE]]`, but using that form in a function still works fine. (i.e. this retrieves the column as I'd expect: `df_fn3 <- function(name) { df[[name, exact=FALSE ]] }`)

Comment: Never mind, I see it. Thanks.

Comment: take a look at the `$` [heading here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html#subsetting-operators). Basically, R interprets `df$name` as `df[["name"]]` rather than resolving out name to `"col1"`

Comment: Yup, thanks! Realized that after staring at my comment to yours for a few seconds and seeing that the function I wrote wasn't literally equivalent to `x[["name", exact=FALSE]]`.

Comment: The $-function does not evaluate its second argument. It needs to be a column name, rather than having a column name as its value..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the `?"$"` docs as per jeremycg's comment:

```
x$name is equivalent to x[["name", exact = FALSE]]
```

When just typing in `df$"col1"` it works. When typing in `df_fn("name")` it doesn't work because, as per the docs, it's literally trying to look up `"name"` as a column. The proof here:

```
> df <- as.data.frame(cbind(col1=c(0,1), col2=c(2,3), name=c(4,5)))
> df_fn("name")
[1] 4 5
```